# get on proxy property 'accessor' is a read-only and non-configurable data property on the proxy target but the proxy did not return its actual value

Tags: arcgis-js-api, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, esri-loader

I want to use vue3 and esri-loader to make a map website.

When using vue-composition-api, I put the Map and MapView objects generated by esri-loader in reactive and export them. But the following happened while reading the properties of the MapView, and I was at a loss.

> 'get' on proxy: property __accessor__ is a read-only and non-configurable data property on the proxy target but the proxy did not return its actual value

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]